# PhpStorm/JetBrains: How to Automatically Upload a Gulp Sass generated CSS file

Tags: sass, gulp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm wrecking my brain trying to figure out how to word this so it's understood.

I'm basically using PhpStorm. I have a gulpfile that generates a minified CSS file from a `src/sass` dir, which gets renamed and placed into the `public/css` folder.

What I would like to do is automatically upload this minified css file to the server using PhpStorm's deployment tools.

I'm able to get all of the .php files to upload (obviously) and the Sass is able to auto-upload (I disabled this), but I can't figure out how to automatically upload the CSS file that's generated. It's annoying having this fluid setup and then having to manually upload the css file each time I do a few edits.

Any ideas? No pun intended, lol.

Comment: Files created/modified by gulp/grunt/etc are considered **external changes** (as they are not created by IDE itself). Therefore you need to enable *similarly named/appropriate option* in Deployment. Once IDE detects changes (e.g. when focus gets back to IDE or by running `File | Synchronize`) the file should be uploaded to current deployment entry. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/options.html -- `Upload external changes` option.

Comment: P.S. As an alternative I may suggest using File Watchers functionality -- it will run any program on file Save -- could be Sass compiler directly .. or your Gulp task. if you correctly configure it (`Output paths to refresh` part) IDE will re-check those files after tool id finished running .. and once modification is detected the Deployment will take place. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/new-watcher-dialog.html

Comment: I think I understood the gist of what you said. I ended up just checking the 'Upload external changes' box and excluding the dev dir. That seems to do what I wanted. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Files created or modified by gulp/grunt/etc are considered **external changes** as they are not created in IDE itself but by some process that runs completely independently (e.g. `gulp -watch`) or was launched from IDE.

Therefore you need to enable similarly named/appropriate option in Deployment option so that IDE can upload them as well. That option is called `Upload external changes` -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/options.html

Once IDE detects changes (e.g. when focus gets back to IDE or by running `File | Synchronize`) the file should be uploaded using current deployment entry in a same fashion as other (modified in IDE) files.